# What is the reason for LCD monitor snow and static?

Tags: display, lcd, interference

This monitor (Iiyama ProLite) is about 5+ years old and worked well until a week ago.

About the issue:

- It appeared from time to time.
- It disappeared after about 1-10 seconds.
- It always disappeared after monitor is turned off and on immediately.
- The snow and static is gray and contains some red, blue and green spots which appeared and disappeared very quickly. Similar to static and interference at cathode-ray monitors. Here is image (color spots can not be viewed due to low resolution)

[image]

**History**

Before I spotted this issue I moved Windows OS from one motherboard to another. And "replaced" the built-in intel video card with Radeon RX550. The cable is the same. But this was about 3 week ago. The problem appeared a bit later.

**Some thoughts**

The problem can be caused by:

- **The Drive**: But in this case power on/off should not "repair" the monitor.
- **The Cable**: But cable is not touched and power button toggle cannot "repair" cable.
- **Monitor Motherboard**: Something wrong with monitor mother board. The most probable cause but I am not sure.

Does anybody know why it happens? Is it monitor issue or not?

**UPDATED**

Monitor connected via DVI-to-HDMI cable.

Comment: What display connection are you using? VGA? DVI? HDMI? DisplayPort?

Comment: What is exact model of Iiyama ProLite is this? Also, 5 years is about the time I had my Samsung LCD screen act up on me in a similar way. No idea what happened but if I connected and disconnected the display cable, the screen wold be clear again. Meaning, this is most likely an issue with a component in the LCD display itself. Might consider the display “dead” and just get a new one.

Comment: Added connection cable to question description.